# Object has no attribute error (Google Machine Learning Tutorial Ep.5)

Tags: python

Hi I'm having some trouble with my code i'm kinda new to python but I do have some understanding of classes and objects.

```
import random
class ScrappyKNN():
    def fit(self,X_train,Y_train):
        self.X_train = X_train
        self.Y_train = Y_train
    def predict(self, X_test,a):
        predictions = []
        for row in X_test:
            label = random.choice(self.Y_train)
            predictions.append(label)
        return predictions

import numpy as np

from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()

X = iris.data
Y = iris.target

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size = .5)

#from sklearn.neighbours import KNeighboursClassifier
my_classifier = ScrappyKNN()

my_classifier = my_classifier.fit(X_train,Y_train)

predictions = my_classifier.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print(accuracy_score(Y_test, predictions))
```

but I'm getting an error when I run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pipelineKNeighbours.py", line 30, in <module>
    predictions = my_classifier.predict(X_test)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
my_classifier = my_classifier.fit(X_train,Y_train)
```

redefines my_classifier as the return value of fit(), which is None,  so my_classifier is no longer pointing to an instance of your ScrappyKNN class, but to a NoneType object - thus, the error.